# How to reduce cost of server-side rendering in Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

We are using Angular2 as our front-end framework and we need to switch from CSR to SSR because of CSR problems with social media crawlers and search engine bots. Since SSR renders the angular pages on a real web server on server-side, it consumes a huge amount of resources such as memory and CPU. Notice that the essence of our app is dynamic and pre-rendering won't help us.

Is there any best practice to earn benefits of both strategies?

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea, but you could enable SSR just for crawlers

Comment: what costs the most?
If it's the CPU you can set up a cache system.